# C# Regex: Capture everything up to

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to capture everything up to (not including) a # sign in a string. The # character may or may not be present (if it's not present, the whole string should be captured).

What would the RegEx and C# code for this by? I've tried: ([^#]+)(?:#) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

<strike>.*(?=#)</strike>

I think that should work

EDIT:

```
^[^#]*
```

In code:

```
string match = Regex.Match(input,"^[^#]*").Value;
```

Comment: Not quite, that will match everything up to the last # .. I think the op wants everything up to the first #

Comment: @Michael Petito: So... add a `?` after the `*`

Comment: @OMG Unicorns because using a lazy quantifier in this case just seems, well, lazy!

Answer (score 2):

Not a regex but an alternative to try. A regex can be used though, but for this particular situation I prefer this method.

```
string mystring = "DFASDFASFASFASFAF#322323"; 
int length = (mystring.IndexOf('#') == -1) ? mystring.Length : mystring.IndexOf('#');
string new_mystring = mystring.Substring(0, length);
```

Comment: I'd prefer this - sometimes there's a simpler solution and regular expressions just aren't needed.

Comment: I agree with Philippe the regex version is far more readable.Though the regex version is only readable to people who knows how to read regex.

Comment: @JohannesH: that's true, but that can easily be solved by a single comment line in the code

Comment: I would prefer the regular expression in this case.  My guess is this regex is actually being used to strip end of line comments indicated by #, as are commonly used in configuration files.  If so, a more complete definition of the expression might strip trailing whitespace and this would be harder to implement (and less clear) using IndexOf and Substring.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with something as simple as:

```
[^#]*
```

Just take the first match?